# Where is Flash installed on OSX?

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/149530/where-is-flash-player-installed) is similar, but it's for Windows.

Where is flash installed on OSX?

I've searched the whole filesystem with `find`, and I see Flash files in the following places:

- `~/Library/Application Support`
- `/private/var/db/receipts`
- `/private/var/db/BootCaches`
- `~/Library/Caches/Adobe/Flash Player`
- `~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player`

Which of these locations (if any) is where Flash is installed? Or is it in another location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no stand-alone application for Flash Player like most software, as it is simply a browser plug-in. If installed, the plug-in file should be located at either `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` or `~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` and should be named `Flash Player.plugin`.

Note if you have Google Chrome, it is built-in to the browser. In modern versions of OS X, Flash Player is no longer installed by default, so if you haven't installed it manually from another browser, it may not be on your system at all.